# Twilio studio connect call to SIP

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to setup a simple flow using Twilio studio, with the last widget being "Connect call to". 
I want to have a caller connected to an agent with a SIP client, registered with the SIP domain in Twilio. The SIP client that's registered to the SIP domain is nothing but a Bria SIP client iOS app that has successfully registered with the SIP domain.
When I type in twilio's SIP domain details as the end point along with the username and password, the flow gets published fine.

When I test the flow by calling the number that triggers the flow, I do get the options as per the flow. I then press certain keys that triggers the "Connect call to" widget in question. At this point, call ends without connecting to the SIP client. I also see this error event, 32009 - The user you tried to dial is not registered with the corresponding SIP Domain.

Am confused. I tried looking into the documentation on Twilio but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the below format, making sure to include the us1 subdomain?

USERNAME@SIPDOMAIN.sip.**us1**.twilio.com